# Best way of building a collection of unique ID's as well as their counts

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I've looked into various different ways of array's, arraylist's, dictionaries... but as I'm used to PHP I'm not entirely sure on the best way I could collect the following information.

My program loops through each user, and if their is a location ID, I want to add that to some sort of collection / array. It's expected that different users will have the same location ID.

If the location ID is the same, I need to increase an integer of how many occurrence for that location ID.

Example:

```
User1 - Location1
User2 - Location3
User3 - Location3

Location1 = 1
Location3 = 2
```

**Also** I need to somehow append each user ID to this collection. So Location3 / 2 occurrences / user2/user3

I've been trying to figure out the best way of doing this for about two hours now, and all the different methods of multidimensional arrays, arraylists, dictionaries is all a little confusing as it all seems abstract to my PHP knowledge. I think C# handles arrays in an entirely different way.

Essentially, the collection with unique location ID's / occurrences / and users collection needs to be stored in something that can be passed to somewhere else in my program as an argument.

**I've made a PHP script which does exactly what I'm after**

```
foreach($call["data"] as $v)
{
    // Foreach USER ($v containing their unique ID and location ID.)

    $user_id        = $v["id"];
    $location_id    = $v["location"]["id"];

    // This adds the location ID as the key within the array, followed by every user who has it. I don't need a count in this case, as I could just count the number of users.
    $collection[$location_id][$user_id] = null;
}
```

This in return creates this array when printed using print_r

```
[106078429431815] => Array
(
    [620790873] => 
    [626276302] => 
    [100000152470577] => 
)
```

(Small part of the output). - Added PHP Example.
Anyone know how I can get C# to collect the same information in the same way my PHP array does?

Comment: How about post your php code for easier understading?

Comment: working on a PHP version with summarized outputs that should clarify things.

Comment: added PHP example with comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;

var grouppingByLocation = users.GroupBy(u => u.LocationID);
foreach (var g in grouppingByLocation)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Location id: {0}", g.Key);
     foreach (var u in g)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("User id: {0}", u.ID);
     }
}
```

See [Enumerable.GroupBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) for more details.

This is an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) over [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface implemented by any built-in collection (such as Array `T[]`, `List<T>`, `Dictionary<K,V>`, etc.) which accepts a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) pointing to a property of class collection of which you're grouping by.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the list looping through initial data, you can create object like this:

```
var list = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, List<int>>();
```

And fill it in the loop

```
if(list[locationID]==null) list[locationID] = Tuple.Create(0,new List<int>());
//..
list[locationId].Item1++;  // counter    
list[locationId].Item2.Add(userId); //list of users
```

Comment: Well, this is cleaner and a bit faster ) I, personally, sometimes use smth like this instead of cryptic linq.

Comment: I think linq is much cleaner and faster in this particular case, it's just `users.GroupBy(u => u.locationID)`

Comment: @KonstantinSpirin adding Count will make it little less cleaner

Comment: @Anri Every group already has `Count()` so you don't really need to add anything.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object to hold each item of data.

```
public Class Model{
        public int LocationId {get;set;}
        public int Occurences{get;set;}
        public IList<User> Users{get;set;}
    }
```

Initialize the container as a list of items.

```
var container = List<Model>();
```

Process you list of users.

```
foreach(var user in userList){
    var model = container.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.LocationId == user.LocationId);

    if(model != null){

       model.Users.Add(user);

    } else{
      model = new Model{
      model.Users = new List<User>.Add(user);
      model.LocationId = user.LocationId;
      container.Add(model)
    }
    model.Occruences ++;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you forgot to put `model` into `container`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var byLocation = users.Where(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Location))
    .GroupBy(u => u.Location);

var stats = byLocation.Select(l => string.Format("{0} / {1} occurrences / {2}",
    l.Key, l.Count(), string.Join("/", l.Select(u => u.User)));

// And just to print the result
foreach (var location in stats)
    Console.WriteLine(location);
```

Comment: So, this is much cleaner? )

Comment: @Anri the first line does grouping and the others are just extra for formatting and printing results, to show usage of `Key` and `Count()`.